# Why did the <div> with the class "container" cling to the left edge?

Tags: html, css

Why is the div with the class “container” clinging to the left edge when the div with the class "boss" is normally displayed in the center?

For a div with a "boss" class, I specified the width and the maximum width and everything works fine, but when I write the same code to the "container" class, the content is pressed to the left

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  background-color: coral;
}

.boss {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  background-color: #313030;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  padding: 40px 30px;
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity: 2;
  background-color: red;
}

.link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="boss">
      <!-- works fine -->
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="button"><a class="link" href="#">HOME</a></div>
        <div class="button"><a class="link" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></div>
        <div class="button"><a class="link" href="#">ABOUT US</a></div>
        <div class="button"><a class="link" href="#">CONTACT</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- have a problem -->
      Example
      <div class="text">
        Example
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't positioned `.container` correctly...if you want it the same as `.boss` then you should give it a `margin: 20px auto`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not write a line "margin: 0px auto" like in class "boss"